# java vector problems

Tags: java, vector

i having an error red underline .add while trying to add items into vector.

any solution please? thanks!!

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.*;

public class AllProduct {

    private Vector<Product> allproducts = new Vector<Product>();

    private Vector<Product> mProduct;

    public  AllProduct () {
        allproducts.add("bb");
    }
...
}
```

Comment: On a side note: The Java API doc has this to say about `Vector`: "Unlike the new collection implementations, `Vector` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"bb"` is a `String`, not a `Product`. You'll need to make a `Product` somehow, e.g. `new Product("bb")`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of Vector to String if you want to add bb

```
private Vector<String> allproducts = new Vector<String>();
```

Comment: That's a bit like saying you should cut your new car in half if it doesn't fit in your garage.